# Find words of specific length in a string php

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops

I need to find words in a string with `length >= 6` and replace any character after the 6th character with `*`.

Seem to be confused how to loop through the $parts array to find those 6 letter words.

Could someone help?

```
$a = 'The game is set in "The City", a dark fantasy world inspired by 
Victorian, Gothic, and steampunk aesthetics. Players control Garrett, a 
master thief who embarks on several missions focusing on stealing from the 
rich. Players may approach levels in a variety of different ways; players 
can choose the action oriented and lethal approach, where players will 
disable or kill enemies on their way to their destination, using knives and 
takedowns, or opt for the non-lethal stealthy approach, where players 
minimize interaction with NPCs and the environment in order to avoid 
detection. Players also may choose which path to take to their destination, 
as each location contains several branching paths.';

$length = 6;

$parts = explode(' ',$a);
```

And then

```
for ($i = 0; $i == $length; $i++){
    echo str_replace($parts, '*', $a);
}
```

Comment: This sounds like homework

Comment: you are passing `$x` instead of `$a` in explode.pass `$a` into explode function.

Comment: @Awaisfiaz oh, yeah. Thanks. Done

Comment: @NigelRen it is, obviously. I have been trying to come up with the solution for a while on my own. Asking out of frustration and being at a dead end. Something wrong with that?

Comment: Difficulty being the answers you get may be way beyond what you've learnt and so it may be obvious that it isn't your own work. Good luck with the course anyway :)

Comment: @Nigel Ren, I see your point. I make sure to go through the solution letter by letter and understand what is happening, and also adjust it if needed. Simple copy/paste won't teach anyone anything :) hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression using [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to transform word of 6 characters length or more. Inside the callback, replace using `substr()` to get the 6 first characters, and append as many `*` as needed to get the size of the word.

```
$a = 'The game is set in "The City", a dark fantasy world inspired by
Victorian, Gothic, and steampunk aesthetics. Players control Garrett, a
master thief who embarks on several missions focusing on stealing from the
rich. Players may approach levels in a variety of different ways; players
can choose the action oriented and lethal approach, where players will
disable or kill enemies on their way to their destination, using knives and
takedowns, or opt for the non-lethal stealthy approach, where players
minimize interaction with NPCs and the environment in order to avoid
detection. Players also may choose which path to take to their destination,
as each location contains several branching paths.';

$a = preg_replace_callback('~\b\w{6,}\b~', function($matches) {
  // return the 6 first characters as clean, and the rest with *
  return substr($matches[0], 0, 6) . str_repeat('*', strlen($matches[0]) - 6);
}, $a);
echo $a ;
```

Outputs:

```
The game is set in "The City", a dark fantas* world inspir** by
Victor***, Gothic, and steamp*** aesthe****. Player* contro* Garret*, a
master thief who embark* on severa* missio** focusi** on steali** from the
rich. Player* may approa** levels in a variet* of differ*** ways; player*
can choose the action orient** and lethal approa**, where player* will
disabl* or kill enemie* on their way to their destin*****, using knives and
takedo***, or opt for the non-lethal stealt** approa**, where player*
minimi** intera***** with NPCs and the enviro***** in order to avoid
detect***. Player* also may choose which path to take to their destin*****,
as each locati** contai** severa* branch*** paths.
```

Regular expression:

```
\b     # wordboundary
\w{6,} # letter of 6 or more length
\b     # wordboundary
```